# Some rows that should be being hidden are not being hidden

Tags: vba, excel

Here is the relevant code:

```
'hides all Location, Account, Product Line, or Sum of Total rows in column A
For Each c In r
    If c.Text = "Location" Or c.Text = "Account" Or c.Text = "Product Line" Or _ 
            c.Text = "Sum of Total" Then
        c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
Next c
```

The issue is that it is hiding most of the columns with those names in column A, but there are two sets where it is not being hidden. (There are ~15 PivotTables, and Location, Account, and Product Line are all filters; Sum of Total is a row that is blank except for that single statement in column A)

What could be causing this?

I can post the full code that I'm using if required, but for some reason it's just not reading the values in the two certain PivotTables.

Edit: more of the code

```
Set r = Range("a1:a1000")

'hides all rows with no value
For Each c In r
    If Len(c.Text) = 0 Then
        c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Else
        c.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
Next c

'unhides all the rows below each grand total row
For Each c In r
    If c.Text = "Grand Total" Then
        c.Offset(1).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If

Next c

'unhides all rows below a row with a value
For Each c In r
    If Len(c.Text) > 0 Then
        c.Offset(1).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
Next c


'hides all Location, Account, Product Line, or Sum of Total rows in column A
For Each c In r
    If c.Text = "Location" Or c.Text = "Account" Or c.Text = "Product Line" _
 Or c.Text = "Sum of Total" Then
        c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
Next c
```

Comment: probably going to need more code (but - unless it's short - not the whole lot!)  [This may help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It's not _particularly_ short. However, this is the last section of the code that should be hiding or unhiding rows. I'll append more of the code onto the question.

Comment: *it's just not reading the values in the two certain pivot tables.* - did you check those pivot tables and verify that the rows match the text you entered **exactly**?

Comment: Yes. More than once. I even removed the filters and put them back on again, just to be sure. I've also copied and pasted the text values from other pivot tables where it is working correctly to the ones where it's not working.

Comment: what happens when you single-step through the code for the offending rows?  Does `c.EntireRow.Hidden = True` execute but not hide the row?  Does the `If` statement skip those rows?

Comment: Is there any way to single step past 500 rows without it going through each one? :/

Comment: yes you can try `For Each c In r.Offset(500)` and you will start immediately at row 500 ;). I second the suggestion of @aucuparia

Comment: set a watch to break on `c.row = 500` or whatever.

Comment: try using instr() to check for those values in your last loop, that will avoid missing an exact match because of an errant whitespace and make sure your range declaration (r) includes all your pivot tables!

Comment: @aucuparia, I've gotten back to the spreadsheet. It goes through the rows that should be hidden but aren't and just skips them. I'm using the same data set for each of the Pivot Tables, and haven't changed any values, so I don't know why the data would be different in these two sets of rows (in addition, it's skipping all 4 rows in each set. There are 15 sets with these 4 rows total, and in the other 13 all 4 rows are being hidden)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem. Instead of using `c.Text` I used `c.Value2` and that fixed the issue. There must have been some internal formatting issue that was unfixable.